# Growth $\beta X\setminus X$ of a Banach space $X$

Tags: banach-spaces, compactness

Is there an analytic characterisation of the Čech-Stone compactification (in the norm topology, which is a normal space) of a Banach space $X$? The reason I ask is because I want to know what the maximal compact extension of such a space could be. For instance, does it matter if the space has the Radon-Nikodým property, as these give a more finite dimensional feel to the measures on the space?

Related is the question that if $X$ is a normed space it can certainly be "too small" to be a Banach space, but if I recall correctly a Tychonoff space always has a completion, so there does exist a Banach space with the norm on $X$. Can $X$ also be too large to be a Banach space? That is, when $X$ itself is already Banach, in what case are larger sets (as in: strict inclusion) no more Banach?

**More explicit:**

1. Let $(X, \|\cdot\|_X)$ be a Banach space, that is, a complete metric space in the induced metric. Can we describe $\beta X \setminus X$ with the topology induced by 1) the norm 2) the weak topology.
2. As in 1., let $(X, \|\cdot\|_X)$ be a Banach space. When can we find a proper supset $Y$ of $X$ (that is $Y \supsetneq X$) such that $(Y, \|\cdot\|_X)$ is still a Banach space?

**Example:** The Sobolev spaces $W_0^{m, p}$ and $W^{m, p}$ which are the closure in the Sobolev $(m, p)$-norm, of the compactly supported smooth and $C^m$ functions respectively.

**Even more explicit:** Consider the open unit disk $\Omega$ in $\mathbf R^2$. On the $L^p(\Omega)$ space we can find subspaces which will carry the Sobolev norm
$$\|u\|_{W^{m, p}(\Omega)} := \sum_{|\alpha| \leqslant m} \|D^\alpha u\|_{L^p(\Omega)}.$$
The compactly supported $C^m$ function in the closure of the $W^{m, p}$ is the space $W_0^{m, p}$. If I take the $C^m$ functions which have finite $W^{m, p}$-norm then I obtain the space $W^{m, p}$ (this is a result by Meyers and Serrin [1964]). Both spaces are obviously Banach. However, $W_0^{m, p}$ will only consist out of functions which have trace zero, that is intuitively speaking, functions which are zero on the boundary of the space. $W^{m, p}$ does not posses such property.

Additionally, we have the obvious chain of embeddings:
$$W_0^{m, p} \hookrightarrow W^{m, p} \hookrightarrow L^p.$$

So, in general, the question is (1) is if $(X, \|\cdot\|_X)$ is a Banach space, does there exist a set $Y$ which contains $X$ and still is *normed* by $\|\cdot\|_X$ that is also Banach and has $X$ embedded?

Indeed, as Old John remarked in chat: $\|\cdot\|_X$ would not be defined on $X$. But, if I am correct and also, given the answer, I can make $X$ 'larger' and still the restriction to $X$ would keep its norm, and there $Y$ could sit.

*I hope this is a better question.*

Comment: All separable infinite-dimensional Banach spaces are homeomorphic, so $\beta X \setminus X$ does not depend on any Banach space properties of $X$. Can you clarify what you mean by "too large to be a Banach space"? Metrizability of a space is an evident obstruction, cardinality isn't, viz $\ell^1(S)$.

Comment: But many interesting examples are *not* separable. Take even a countable tensor product of Hilbert spaces, a bosonic Fock space for instance.

Comment: I answered your question on the RN-property which a separable Banach space may or may not have, while $\beta X \setminus X$ is always the same in this case.

Comment: Ah - I see! But separable spaces are usually not the interesting cases. $L^\infty$? I would be quite surprised if you now tell me all non-separable ones are homeomorphic as well!

Comment: 2) The only such subsets are closed subspaces.

Comment: suPset. I do know a little bit of elementary metric space theory. Maybe not that much, but at least that...

Comment: @JonasTeuwen: In 2., $\|\cdot\|_X$ is a function from $X$ to $[0,\infty)$, so it is not defined on $Y$ technically (this is obvious and I only mention it to establish context for my comment).  Do you mean that $Y$ is also a normed space, and that the restriction of its norm to $X$ equals $\|\cdot\|_X$?  I would guess this strictly based on the wording of the question, but I guess not, because your comment on Piotr's answer seems to indicate that it does not answer the question.  Could you please explain that question a little more?

Comment: @JonasMeyer Yes, I think I must have misunderstood the reply. I do want $X$ to at least continuously be included in $Y$. It is quite a simple example and was not really what I had in mind. Showing that Banach spaces are not so easy to grasp intuitively! :-). So you have understood the question!

Comment: @JonasMeyer I had in mind the above Sobolev spaces on domains where one only can describe Dirichlet problems. I need to figure out how to characterize that.

Comment: @JonasTeuwen: Thanks. I am wondering if maybe you have in mind something like the following vague setup: The elements of $X$ and $Y$ are functions and the norm is defined in some natural way on $Y$ (and $X$) in terms of the functions, and if we start with $X$, when is it possible to enlarge the class of functions so that the way of defining the norm on $X$ still makes sense on elements of $Y$ and defines a Banach space norm?

Comment: E.g., the sup norm on the space of continuous functions on a compact space can be extended to the space of all bounded functions on the same space, but if you started with the space of all bounded functions, how would you extend in a way that preserves the meaning of the norm?  Or in your Sobolev example, if the functions are not at least $C^k$ then the extended norm would not have the same meaning, right?  Is this the idea?

Comment: @JonasMeyer Yes. As in my Sobolev space, if I take the circle and functions with compact support on the circle and take the closure in the norm $W^{m, p}$ where the functions are at least $C^m$ then I get a different space than if I start with $C^m$ functions without the compact support. Namely, the first space will have functions with trace null, whereas the second one will have much more. They only coincide whenever the complement if their domain is $(m , q)$-polar. Both norms make sense. But $W_0^{m, p}$ is a strict subset.

Comment: I wish to figure out how common this phenomenon is. It is clear that I cannot make $W^{m, p}$ larger in this sense as that would involve things having non-finite norm. But I can make $W_0^{m, p}$ --which is as much Banach as $W^{m, p}$-- larger. I am starting to wonder if the question would be of enough 'level' to ask on MO. I did not as I might need to be able to phrase it better...

Comment: I would work on making it more precise first; I only have a vague sense of what the question is, and I do not know a way to make it precise in an interesting way.  (Maybe that is just me.)

Comment: At least it was stupid enough for someone to downvote it! I will attempt to phrase the question in a more meaningful way.

Comment: There is one thing that becomes more and more unclear to me with your edits: what do all the additions (after 2.) have to with the Cech-Stone compactification?

Comment: **Nothing**. Does that answer your question 8-)? I would like to know what $\beta W_0^{m, p}\setminus W_0^{m, p}$ is nevertheless.

Comment: Then maybe you should separate the two (seemingly) unrelated questions. In any case: I doubt that there is much explicit to say about $\beta X \setminus X$. After all, what is $\beta \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \mathbb{R}^n$? As I mentioned in my first comment: for separable infinite-dimensional spaces you get $\beta \mathbb{R}^\infty \setminus \mathbb{R}^\infty$ irrespective of your Banach space.

Comment: Here is an alternative (vague) approach that might be in the direction of what you're looking for: try to embed your space of functions into a huge space like $L^p_{\rm loc}$, $L^0$ or a space of distributions and try to define a natural (extended) norm on that huge space (allow it to take the value $\infty$). Under mild conditions the collection of functions with finite norm will be a Banach space that might be strictly larger than your original space. See for instance the entry on [Banach function spaces](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Banach_function_space) in the ecyclopedia.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the link. I had something like that in mind - Topologically dualize a test function space and sqeeuze the Banach space in between.

Answer (score 4):

Concerning the second part of your question, when $X$ is a Banach space, one can always find a "larger" Banach space containing $X$ as a proper, closed subspace.

Indeed, if $Y$ is another Banach space one can endow the direct product $X \times Y$ with a norm making it a Banach space with $X \simeq X \times \{ 0 \}, Y \simeq \{ 0 \} \times Y$ as closed subspaces. Such a norm is certainly not unique, but one example is given by $|| (x, y) || = || x || _{X} + || y || _{Y}$. There exists Banach spaces $Y$ of arbitrary cardinality, since $L^{1}(\Omega)$ is a Banach space of cardinality at least $| \Omega |$ for any set $\Omega$, so one can make $X \times Y$ arbitrarily large too.

Comment: The question is giving a Banach space $X$ with a norm $\|\cdot\|_X$, can we enlarge $X$ to make the enlargement with norm $\|\cdot\|_X$ not complete anymore?

Comment: @JonasTeuwen: I do not understand what that means.  Could you please elaborate?